# Передача данных между формами POST

Tags: php

У меня в методе POST хранятся данные, которые мне нужно передавать через форму.

```
<form id="slick-login" method="post">
        <label for="username">Логин:</label><input type="text" name="username" class="placeholder" placeholder="Логин">
        <label for="password">Пароль:</label><input type="password" name="password" class="placeholder" placeholder="Пароль">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ВОЙТИ"  >
                <input type="button" value="РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ" onClick="window.location='RegPage.php'">
                <script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;theme=classic;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,twitter,facebook;hidden=;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F;mobilebuttons=0;"></div>
    </form>

$login = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $query= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login='$login'") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
     $user_data= mysqli_fetch_array($query);
     if($user_data['password']==$password)
     {

        header("Location: AddPage.php");
     }
```

Как пользоваться данными в Post на странице AddPagge.php

Comment: если делать как в коде в вопросе, то только через гет `header("Location: AddPage.php?data=666&data2=валправполр");`  или через сессию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пытаюсь решить при помощи сессии. Я её открыл и выполнил инициализацию.(session_start(); $_SESSION['Login']=$login, но в моей второй странице значения нул, что я делаю не так?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нужно ли что-либо делать с сессией во второй странице?

Comment: ну по идее тоже `session_start` там нужен.